# How do I use a multi-word model name when using ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm having trouble using multi-word model names in conjunction with ember-cli.

I'm getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: Encountered "phrase_token" in payload, but no model was found
for model name "phraseToken" (resolved model name using
DS.ActiveModelSerializer.typeForRoot("phrase_token"))
```

I'm doing my find as follows:

```
store.find('phrase-token', 123).then(function(m) { ... })
```

The JSON returned by my server uses the root `phrase_token` as I am using the `ActiveModelAdapter`.

One theory I have is that Ember-data is trying to use camelCase model names, but this isn't found by the ember-cli resolver that uses dasherized names.

I also tried the following:

```
store.find('phraseToken', 123).then(function(m) { ... })
```

but that fails saying there's no such model.

**Update:**

I noticed that this only happens in unit tests. I realize in my question I failed to mention that I ran into this problem when testing. In my full application, I don't actually have the problem at all.

I declare my test module as follows:

```
moduleForModel 'phrase-token', 'PhraseToken', {
  # Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  needs: ['adapter:application', 'serializer:application']
}
```

I think it comes down to the difference that in my full application (with a fully populated container, etc.) I can do the following:

```
!!store.modelFactoryFor('phrase-token')   # true
!!store.modelFactoryFor('phraseToken')    # true
```

but in my unit test:

```
!!store.modelFactoryFor('phrase-token')   # true
!!store.modelFactoryFor('phraseToken')    # false
```

**Update 2:**

I have found that performing the following in my setup code for my unit tests solves the problem:

```
container.normalizeFullName = function(fullName) {
  fullName.dasherize()
});
```

But it feels like this shouldn't necessary, so I'm holding out for a different answer.

**Update 3:**

I posted an [issue](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/issues/119) about this and the 0.2.0 release of `ember-qunit` has fixed the problem.

Comment: Yeah naming conventions need to match in ember. Think you'd need to change your incoming payload to match names or change it on the ember side when it comes in.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the active model adapter is to allow underscore names server-side. So I don't think I should need to change my payload.

Comment: Ah yes maybe. Sorry I havent used the active model serialiser, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply always use the dasherized name when you reference the model in your code - just like you name your files, everything else is deprecated to my knowledge. That doesn't affect your JSON payload though.

Comment: I am always using dasherized names. The problem is Ember internally converts this to a camelCase name and then tries to resolve using that, which in normal operation works, but not when testing.

Comment: The code you shared shows something different. You are trying to use a camel cased name which fails in tests.  I am very sure that you can use phrase-token everywhere and it will work - except for in the json payload there you need to use the underscore version probably.

Comment: I am showing you the behavior with camelCase names to illustrate the behavior of Ember and how it differs between unit tests and when the full application is loaded. I am not using camelCase in my application. However, as I said, Ember is still internally converting to camelCase and performing lookups on the container that way, which happen to work when the full app is loaded, but not in unit tests. The lookup that causes the problem is buried deep in the Ember Data code and there are no camelCase instances of model names in my code.

Comment: Ah. I assume this is specific to the active model adapter then and sort of a bug in ember data. Just continue using the dash version and expect the problem to solve itself. which version of ember data are you on? Did you try canary?

Comment: Yeah, I think it will get resolved. I posted a workaround (update 2) that I'll go with for now. I'm using ember-data 1.0.0-beta.14.1 and ember 1.9.1. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like someone else is having the same issue and it's indeed in ember-data: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3178